# Convert Csv file to jtl file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to generate html report that's why I have to convert csv file to JTL file .there is any option to convert, because I have aggregate CSV Report

Answer (score 0):

If you executed your test in JMeter GUI mode with [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener enabled and used "Save Table Data" button you will only have the metrics which are visible in the table.

[image]

There is no way to get individual SampleResults from the CSV output of the Aggregate Report listener.

You will need to [re-run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) and provide the desired .jtl file location via [`-l` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options). In this case you will get the .jtl file with all the metrics and you will be able to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_after_load_test) from it.

You can even generate the dashboard during the test:

```
jmeter -n -t -f /path/to/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/results/file.jtl -e -o /path/to/dashboard/folder
```